# How can I write ped file from r to epacts

Tags: r, genetics

Is there a package which allows me to write a .ped file from my R-dataset to use with EPACTS with an appropiate header?

I cannot google it and only find a way to read it

Answer (score 0):

A web search reveals that there is no tool to do this. You may want to consider using VCF format, as EPACTS seems to accept this:

http://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/EPACTS#VCF_file_for_Genotypes

You can convert PED to VCF using plink like so:

```
plink --file prefix --recode vcf --out prefix
```

You may need to fiddle with additional option to get it to produce output you want, see https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2/data#recode, specfically:

```
    The 'vcf', 'vcf-fid', and 'vcf-iid' modifiers result in production of a 
VCFv4.2 file. 'vcf-fid' and 'vcf-iid' cause family IDs and within-family IDs 
respectively to be used for the sample IDs in the last header row, while 
'vcf' merges both IDs and puts an underscore between them (in this case, a 
warning will be given if an ID already contains an underscore).
    If the 'bgz' modifier is added, the VCF file is block-gzipped. (Gzipping 
of other --recode output files is not currently supported.)
    The A2 allele is saved as the reference and normally flagged as not 
based on a real reference genome ('PR' INFO field value). When it is 
important for reference alleles to be correct, you'll usually also want to 
include --a2-allele and --real-ref-alleles in your command.
```

Answer (score 0):

EPACTS needs both a VCF and PED file as input for association analysis. Unlike the PED file described in the [PLINK documentation](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2/formats#ped), the PED file used in EPACTS does not contain genotype data. Its purpose is to hold your phenotype data and covariates, and it needs a .ped extension to be recognized by EPACTS.

To export a data frame in R as a PED file you just need to specify that a .ped extension is needed; you can use the following command:

```
write.table(df, filename.ped, sep="\t", row.names=F, col.names=T, quote=F)
```

EPACTS also requires that the header line containing the column names be commented out. I usually just do this step manually since adding in the '#' is very quick, and I always open my file to check it anyway. Alternatively you could set col.names=F and use a .dat file as shown in the EPACTS documentation here: https://genome.sph.umich.edu/wiki/EPACTS#PED_file_for_Phenotypes_and_Covariates